# Center Surfaces inside SequentialLayout (famo.us)

Tags: famo.us

I am trying to solve the problem of centering Surfaces with different widths inside a vertical SequentialLayout, in famo.us. I've gone through the Famo.us University and the source code on the github site, but couldn't figure out a "clean" solution..

For instance, the following code is adapted from http://famo.us/university/lessons/#/layout/sequential-layout/2 to create surfaces with different widths:

```
var Engine = require("famous/core/Engine");
var Surface = require("famous/core/Surface");
var SequentialLayout = require("famous/views/SequentialLayout");

var mainContext = Engine.createContext();
var sequentialLayout = new SequentialLayout();
var surfaces = [];
sequentialLayout.sequenceFrom(surfaces);

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    surfaces.push(new Surface({
        size: [i*35, 50],   // <- Changed the width here!!!
        properties: {
            backgroundColor: "hsl(" + (i * 360 / 10) + ", 100%, 50%)",
        }
    }));
}

mainContext.add(sequentialLayout);
```

The result can be seen at https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEh2Y.png (I don't have enough "reputation" to post images, sorry!)

I've tried to add a Modifier to add each Surface to, however, Modifiers do not have the **add** function. Any other simple solutions to center horizontally all those Surfaces?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a modifier by adding it first to a RenderNode, and then adding the surface to the RenderNode. This should do the trick:

```
var RenderNode = require('famous/core/RenderNode');

var node = new RenderNode(new Modifier({
    align: [0.5, 0],
    origin: [0.5, 0]
}));
node.add(new Surface({
    size: [i*35, 50],   // <- Changed the width here!!!
    properties: {
        backgroundColor: "hsl(" + (i * 360 / 10) + ", 100%, 50%)",
    }
}));
surfaces.push(node);
```

Comment: It works, thanks! :)

But I keep wondering why is the famo.us API so non-intuitive.. RenderNode should be an implementation detail, not a public API. This could be fixed if the famo.us API had an *add* function on layouts like it has for the views and contexts..

Comment: I expanded on @ijzerenhein for fun using proportions **[Click Here for a jsBin Example](http://jsbin.com/layoqo/1/edit?js,output)**. Click anywhere to see the transitions.

Comment: @JoãoVentura Yes I completely agree. Having to write all those modifiers and render-nodes all the time can be a real pain. I created an alternative solution for doing layout with famo.us called famous-flex (https://github.com/IjzerenHein/famous-flex). I write most of my views using a LayoutController and a layout function, it's way faster. The famous-flex lib still needs a better tutorial for using LayoutController's, I will hopefully get around to that soon.